# How can I troubleshoot empty data values when saving to MongoDB in Golang?

Tags: mongodb, go, go-gin

I'm a newcomer to Golang, and I'm facing an issue with saving data to a database. After receiving a JSON object from an API, I'm attempting to store it in MongoDB, but the data is being saved with empty values.

Here's my code and structures:

```
var current:={
    "usd": {
        "code": "USD",
        "alphaCode": "USD",
        "numericCode": "840",
        "name": "U.S. Dollar",
        "rate": 0.68135437808647,
        "date": "Sun, 31 Dec 2023 11:55:01 GMT",
        "inverseRate": 1.4676650391657
    },
    "eur": {
        "code": "EUR",
        "alphaCode": "EUR",
        "numericCode": "978",
        "name": "Euro",
        "rate": 0.61624276207684,
        "date": "Sun, 31 Dec 2023 11:55:01 GMT",
        "inverseRate": 1.6227371119619
    },
    "gbp": {
        "code": "GBP",
        "alphaCode": "GBP",
        "numericCode": "826",
        "name": "U.K. Pound Sterling",
        "rate": 0.53541690218052,
        "date": "Sun, 31 Dec 2023 11:55:01 GMT",
        "inverseRate": 1.8677034586085
    }
}
```

This is my model.go

```
type Currency struct {
    Code        string  `json:"code"`
    AlphaCode   string  `json:"alphaCode"`
    NumericCode string  `json:"numericCode"`
    Name        string  `json:"name"`
    Rate        float64 `json:"rate"`
    Date        string  `json:"date"`
    InverseRate float64 `json:"inverseRate"`
}

type Rate struct {
    ID        primitive.ObjectID `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Currency  `json:"currency"`
    Timestamp primitive.DateTime `json:"timestamp"`
}
```

I try to save data to DB but I write only default values with empty strings and 0

```
const apiUrl = "https://www.floatrates.com/daily/aud.json" 
func GetRatesFromAPI() (map[string]models.Rate, error) {
    response, err := http.Get(apiUrl)
    fmt.Print(response)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var data map[string]models.Rate
    if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &data); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    fmt.Print(data)
    return data, nil
}
    r.GET("/get", func(c *gin.Context) {
      mongo.ConnectDB()
          rates, err := src.GetRatesFromAPI()
      fmt.Print(rates)
          if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
      }
      for _, rate := range rates {
        mongo.InsertRate(rate)
       }

      c.String(http.StatusOK, "get rates")
    })
func InsertRate(rate models.Rate) {
    rate.Timestamp = primitive.NewDateTimeFromTime(time.Now())
    collection := client.Database("mongodb").Collection("rates")
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    result, err := collection.InsertOne(ctx, rate)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Println("Inserted rate with ID:", result.InsertedID)
}
```

I get this object in DB without any values I'm trying to figure out why the data is not being stored correctly in MongoDB. Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
[
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "659177abefa699e213158c16"},
    "currency": {
      "code": "",
      "alphacode": "",
      "numericcode": "",
      "name": "",
      "rate": 0,
      "date": "",
      "inverserate": 0
    },
    "timestamp": {"$date": "2023-12-31T14:16:11.800Z"}
  }
]
```

Comment: The `Rate` type embeds the `Currency` type. Are you sure this is what you wanted? A regular field may look like this: `Currency Currency` (note the name and type).

Comment: @icza I tried doing it without Rate, but the result was the same — all values were empty. I'm still a newcomer to Go, so I don't know how to implement it correctly

Comment: Your code should work. If the inserted currency is empty, I'm guessing the value you insert is also empty. Try printing it to the console like: `log.Printf("%+v", rate)` right before  calling `collection.InsertOne()`, and let's see what gets printed on your cosole.

Comment: Perhaps, here response, err := http.Get(apiUrl) I might be retrieving it incorrectly, as this request indeed returns an empty value. However, when I make the request through Postman to this API, the JSON in the response is not empty. How can I retrieve these values correctly

Comment: In that case your Go model does not properly model your input JSON. You should post your input JSON so we can tell what's wrong.

Comment: I am receiving JSON from "https://www.floatrates.com/daily/aud.json", e.g. {
    "usd": {
        "code": "USD",
        "alphaCode": "USD",
        "numericCode": "840",
        "name": "U.S. Dollar",
        "rate": 0.68135437808647,
        "date": "Sun, 31 Dec 2023 11:55:01 GMT",
        "inverseRate": 1.4676650391657
    },
    "eur": {
        "code": "EUR",
        "alphaCode": "EUR",
        "numericCode": "978",
        "name": "Euro",
        "rate": 0.61624276207684,
        "date": "Sun, 31 Dec 2023 11:55:01 GMT",
        "inverseRate": 1.6227371119619
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises from embedding the `Currency` type within the `Rate` type using the json tag `json:"currency"`. However, the input JSON provided for `json.Unmarshal` does not contain a corresponding "`currency`" field. Consequently, all fields within the `Currency` type receive zero values, which are then stored in MongoDB. To address this, you can either eliminate the json tag `json:"currency"` during the embedding of the `Currency` type (as shown below) or structure the target object to align with the structure of the input JSON.

```golang
type Rate struct {
    ID        primitive.ObjectID `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Currency 
    Timestamp primitive.DateTime `json:"timestamp"`
}
```